# Changing a htaccess rewrite rule to this?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use this rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /used-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

to rerwrite all the www.domain.com/1234 to www.domain.com/used-details.php?id=1234

and it works correctly.

How can have the www.domain.com/used-details/1234 instead of the www.domain.com/1234

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule used-details/(.*)/ used-details.php?id=$1
```

Comment: When I visit the new url, all the css, js are not shown because of the structure. style.css it is in the root folder, but now the code tries to locate it into the /used-details/ non existed folder...

Comment: The best way to give link to your css or js is to append it with the base URL .For example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo URL;?>style.css">` Where the URL is base URL, and you can save it as , `define("URL",     "http://localhost/your-site/");`
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^used-details/([0-9]+)/?$ /used-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It will change `www.domain.com/used-details/1234` to `www.domain.com/used-details.php?id=1234`

Comment: When I visit the new url, all the css, js are not shown because of the structure. style.css it is in the root folder, but now the code tries to locate it into the /used-details/ non existed folder...

Comment: Try putting a `/` before the css/js links? So `style.css` would be `/style.css`